# How to drop packet in mobile adhoc simulation in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I'm new in ns3. i'm  simulating mobile adhoc network with AODV protocol in NS3.
I want to drop the routing packets randomly with 10% probability.but I don't know how it's possible!!
I'll be thankful if somebody help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are so  many things that have not been solved in NS3. but I think this question might have been answered at this link.[**GOOGLE groups "Does the AODV simulation drop any packets ?**
"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-3-users/rzSlNL8vTxY) .